# Sum of values MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with 3 columns:

```
id, product, Date and Value
```

I want to add all the values of all the rows of a product on a concrete day.

The result would be:

```
PRODUCT, DATE, SUM(VALUE)
```

I hope I explained well.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/1002/aggregate-functions/3254/sum#t=201607291138066973297

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by the distinct values you want in your result - in this case, the combination of the `product` and the `date`:

```
SELECT   `product`, `date`, SUM(`value`)
FROM     `mytable`
GROUP BY `product`, `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
Make use of `GROUP BY`

```
select PRODUCT, DATE, SUM(VALUE) from your_tbl group by PRODUCT, DATE;
```